# Disable the default Piggyback SSL on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, heroku

I have two domain names pointing to one Heroku app. One domain name is always used over https. I have a wildcard certificate for that domain. That, combined with the fact that I can only have 1 SSL certificate installed on a Heroku app, leaves me to force the other domain name to http. I have installed the SslEnforcer gem to take care of this for me. However, since Heroku now gives me default Piggyback SSL on my app, when I try to access my non-secure domain over https, it first hits the Piggyback SSL certificate, which yields a security error, since I'n not on the *.herokuapp.com domain. It never got to the SslEnforcer redirect.

So it seems that I desperately need to disable or remove the default Piggyback SSL. Is there a way to do so? Or is there another solution anyone can think of?

Comment: Why not ask Heroku? They have pretty decent support.

Comment: +1 for asking heroku support.

Comment: Why are people hitting your non secure domain via https in the firs tplace? Any domain that points at heroku will give a security error if you attempt to access it via https.